# How can I create profiles for the windows that are open on my Mac?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, display, window-manager

As a semi-dual monitor user on my MacBook, I run into a particular issue that drives me nuts. The scenario is at work I run my MacBook Pro's display as the secondary monitor to a dual-monitor setup. I primarily use the secondary view for my social network windows (Adium, Tweetie, Gabbble, and IRC). I position exactly as I want them to see all at the same time.

However, when I disconnect my MBP to go home and reconnect to my other monitor at home, all the applications were shifted onto the main screen (since that is where they went when I disconnected the monitor before I left). With this, I have to go through the whole process again to move and position them on the secondary screen again.

Is there a utility or application that will allow me to create screen/window profiles that will basically memorize the current position of all the windows and persist it to be re-instantiated later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) is a product built exactly for this purpose.  You set a window setup for each monitor configuration that you use, then use Stay to restore to your setup at any time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a pretty good start and is pretty much what I was looking for:
http://www.jonathanlaliberte.com/2009/02/04/restore-previous-display-window-positions-applescript/